# Drag and Drop in Swift - Issues with Registering for Dragged Types?

Tags: drag-and-drop, swift

### Background

I am trying to do some simple Drag and Drop in Swift similar to the sample code from Apple for [Cocoa Drag and Drop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaDragAndDrop/Introduction/Intro.html). I am not getting far before I have errors.

I have created a swift class dropView with code at bottom. self.registered for types seems like it worked as I get a long list of image types or the shorter list.

When I set the array for registering dragging types to TIF and jpeg types, I get no response for draggingEntered or draggingUpdated. It seems that I am missing something simple? I have the custom view set to the dropView class.

Separately, I get a host of errors when I drag a file (at least for TIF and jpeg) when the array is set to NSImage.imagePasteBoardTypes() see ** at bottom of post.

### Questions

Why is draggingEntered or draggingUpdated not being called?

Other questions:

Am I registering for dragged types correctly?
Is the array in the right format?
Is the NSDraggingDestination property bit at the top of the file in the right spot?

### Code

```
import Cocoa

class dropView: NSView, NSDraggingDestination {

init(frame: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    //let theArray = [NSImage.imagePasteboardTypes()]
    let theArray = ["NSTypedFilenamesPboardType:jpg",
        "NSTypedFilenamesPboardType:JPG",
        "NSTypedFilenamesPboardType:jpeg",
        "NSTypedFilenamesPboardType:JPEG",
        "NSTypedFilenamesPboardType:jpe",
        "NSTypedFilenamesPboardType:TIF"]

    registerForDraggedTypes(theArray)
    println("INIT and REGISTER")
    println(self.registeredDraggedTypes)
}

override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

    // Drawing code here.
}


override func draggingEntered(sender: NSDraggingInfo!) -> NSDragOperation {
    println("Dragging Entered")
    return NSDragOperation.Copy
}

override func draggingUpdated(sender: NSDraggingInfo!) -> NSDragOperation  {
    println("UPDATED")
    return NSDragOperation.Copy
}

}
```

### ** Errors when NSImage.imagePasteBoardTypes()

```
2014-06-21 11:34:38.728 DragAndDrop[96606:303] -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x610000049d80  
2014-06-21 11:34:38.729 DragAndDrop[96606:303] -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x610000049d80  
2014-06-21 11:34:38.730 DragAndDrop[96606:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ddaf25c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff83a5de75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ddb212d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dd0d322 ___forwarding___ + 1010
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dd0cea8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   LaunchServices                      0x00007fff8aee1b0a XCFStringHashCaseInsensitive + 111
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dc6afd8 CFBasicHashFindBucket + 1032
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dc989c9 CFSetGetValueIfPresent + 121
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dc9892c -[__NSCFSet member:] + 28
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dccb008 -[NSSet containsObject:] + 24
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dd18fcf -[NSSet intersectsSet:] + 735
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff86c645ff -[NSView(NSDrag) _hitTest:dragTypes:] + 221
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff86c645d2 -[NSView(NSDrag) _hitTest:dragTypes:] + 176
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff86c645d2 -[NSView(NSDrag) _hitTest:dragTypes:] + 176
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff86c6438c -[NSWindow(NSDrag) _findDragTargetFrom:] + 111
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff86c63280 NSCoreDragTrackingProc + 476
    16  HIServices                          0x00007fff8b8a05a3 DoEnterLeaveHandler + 389
    17  HIServices                          0x00007fff8b8a2fdd CoreDragMessageHandler + 1741
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dd5ace8 __CFMessagePortPerform + 760
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dce08d9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dce084e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 478
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dcd1886 __CFRunLoopRun + 1830
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dcd0f25 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
    23  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8b908a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
    24  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8b9087b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
    25  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8b9085bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8695726e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff869568bb -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
    28  AppKit                              0x00007fff8694a9bc -[NSApplication run] + 553
    29  AppKit                              0x00007fff869357a3 NSApplicationMain + 940
    30  DragAndDrop                         0x00000001000033fd top_level_code + 109
    31  DragAndDrop                         0x000000010000343a main + 42
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8e1925fd start + 1
    33  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
2014-06-21 11:34:40.729 DragAndDrop[96606:303] -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x610000049d80
2014-06-21 11:34:40.730 DragAndDrop[96606:303] -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x610000049d80
2014-06-21 11:34:40.731 DragAndDrop[96606:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ddaf25c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff83a5de75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8ddb212d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dd0d322 ___forwarding___ + 1010
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dd0cea8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   LaunchServices                      0x00007fff8aee1b0a XCFStringHashCaseInsensitive + 111
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dc6afd8 CFBasicHashFindBucket + 1032
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dc989c9 CFSetGetValueIfPresent + 121
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dc9892c -[__NSCFSet member:] + 28
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dccb008 -[NSSet containsObject:] + 24
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dd18fcf -[NSSet intersectsSet:] + 735
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff86c645ff -[NSView(NSDrag) _hitTest:dragTypes:] + 221
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff86c645d2 -[NSView(NSDrag) _hitTest:dragTypes:] + 176
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff86c645d2 -[NSView(NSDrag) _hitTest:dragTypes:] + 176
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff86c6438c -[NSWindow(NSDrag) _findDragTargetFrom:] + 111
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff86c63280 NSCoreDragTrackingProc + 476
    16  HIServices                          0x00007fff8b89fca4 DoTrackingMessage + 370
    17  HIServices                          0x00007fff8b8a2b36 CoreDragMessageHandler + 550
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dd5ace8 __CFMessagePortPerform + 760
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dce08d9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dce084e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 478
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dcd1886 __CFRunLoopRun + 1830
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dcd0f25 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
    23  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8b908a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
    24  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8b9087b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
    25  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8b9085bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8695726e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff869568bb -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
    28  AppKit                              0x00007fff8694a9bc -[NSApplication run] + 553
    29  AppKit                              0x00007fff869357a3 NSApplicationMain + 940
    30  DragAndDrop                         0x00000001000033fd top_level_code + 109
    31  DragAndDrop                         0x000000010000343a main + 42
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8e1925fd start + 1
    33  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Swift 3, Xcode 8b6, OSX 10.11)

[Apple recommends](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nspasteboard/1654154-types_for_standard_data_os_x_v10) that the older style of pasteboard types should no longer be used and to use [UTIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Type_Tag_Classes) where possible - the better version is

```
self.register(forDraggedTypes: [kUTTypeURL as String])
```

This means that you receive drags from the Finder, for all filetypes.

Since `NSImage.imagePasteboardTypes` has been deprecated without replacement, you should handle the filtering in draggingEntered:

```
override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        let pasteboard = sender.draggingPasteboard()
        let filteringOptions = [NSPasteboardURLReadingContentsConformToTypesKey:NSImage.imageTypes()]
                if pasteboard.canReadObject(forClasses: [NSURL.self], options: filteringOptions) {
                        return NSDragOperation.copy
        }      
        return NSDragOperation() //alternatively: []
}
```

(credit for the use of NSPasteboardURLReadingContentsConformToTypesKey goes to @TroutDev's [tutorial here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136272/drag-and-drop-tutorial-for-macos))

Comment: In Xcode 9 it's `registerForDraggedTypes([.URL])`. Also, `NSPasteboardURLReadingContentsConformToTypesKey` is gone, not sure what the replacement is.

Answer (score 6):

### Regarding the crash

> Separately, I get a host of errors when I drag a file (at least for TIF and jpeg) when the array is set to NSImage.imagePasteBoardTypes() see ** at bottom of post.

`NSImage.imagePasteboardTypes()` already returns an array, so using it like this:

```
let theArray = NSImage.imagePasteboardTypes()
```

instead of like this

```
let theArray = [NSImage.imagePasteboardTypes()]
```

will fix the crash.

### Regarding NSDragDestination

> Why is draggingEntered or draggingUpdated not being called?

If you're dragging from Finder, you probably want `let types = [NSFilenamesPboardType]`. The code you have means you have to place data onto the pasteboard yourself -- Finder doesn't put file contents onto the pasteboard, it puts filenames.

> Is the NSDraggingDestination property bit at the top of the file in the right spot?

Yep! `: NSDraggingDestination` tells Swift that you're about to implement the protocol.

### Working example

```
// Public domain
import Cocoa

class DragView: NSView, NSDraggingDestination {
    init(frame: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        let types = [NSFilenamesPboardType]
        registerForDraggedTypes(types)
        println(self.registeredDraggedTypes)
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect)  {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
        NSColor.whiteColor().set()
        NSRectFill(dirtyRect)
    }

    override func draggingEntered(sender: NSDraggingInfo!) -> NSDragOperation  {
        println("hello")
        return NSDragOperation.Copy
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. As I was starting from this example, [Cocoa Drag and Drop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CocoaDragAndDrop/Introduction/Intro.html), So if I read the NSPasteboard class documentations, the the objective-C code works with [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSImage imagePasteboardTypes]]; has been deprecated in 10.10?