# XCode: Swift strange behaviour and errors

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm new to Swift, I'm trying to create a new Cocoa Application based on the following code:

[Drag and Drop in Swift - Issues with Registering for Dragged Types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343216/drag-and-drop-in-swift-issues-with-registering-for-dragged-types)

I'm doing this:

1. create Swift Cocoa Application
2. add a Custom View
3. add a Swift Class subclass of NSView named DropView
4. set the Custom View class to DropView
5. paste the referenced code in DropView

Then I'm getting a few errors, and I'm not really understanding why and how to solve it. Can someone help me?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first error says, you need to add the `override` to your `init` method:

```
override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frameRect)
}
```

Also there are some changes in the `draggingEntered` and the `draggingUpdated` methods. You don't need the `!` for your `NSDraggingInfo` anymore:

```
override func draggingEntered(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
    return NSDragOperation.Copy
}

override func draggingUpdated(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
    return NSDragOperation.Copy
}
```

To check the correct implementation of a method you want to override, just start typing the method-name in your file and Xcode will create you the method with header etc:

[image]

To fix your last error, you need to implement the `required init` the `NSView` needs:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
```

To help you for further errors like these: Often Xcode itself helps you to solve the problems. Especially if you see the round error-circle on the left side of your editor. Just click on it and check what Xcode recommends:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you for all the info. I tried that but seems like the DropView class is not being called. I can't manage to log the init method.

Comment: But that is another problem and not related to the errors you get. You should ask another question asking for that problem.